# cPanel : Running an application

Tags: cpanel, middleware

I am trying to build a middleware application ( you know...retrive data from a webservice and store to db in cPAnel and send the data to the webservice hosted from here)

1. Is it possible to run an application in cPanel?
2. If it is possible what is the prefferedlanguage for this purpose and
   why?
3. If I am trying to run an application which has to update this fetch
   hourly automatically form code.is it possible.means i want this
   application to be in running state for an indefinite time.Is it
   possible?

Comment: Please let me know why the -ve so that i can improve my question

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are:
1. cPanel is not a jumping off point for applications.  It is simply a shared hosting management console.  It gives you  the ability to do some management.   You can fire off applications by making a cronjob.

1. Generally you have two choices, you can use shell scripting or PHP invoked from a shell.
2. Now this narrows it down further.  PHP is configured to have a maximum execution time to stop people hogging the processors.

If you are going to write some proper middleware, I'd suggest that you either get yourself an Amazon, Jelastic or some other cloud hosting provider.  You will get the ability to deploy a real application, on a full operating system - rather than "hacking" a solution.

cPanel based installs are really for those people who just want to put a website, whack up a blog, or do some low bandwidth hosting.  Running something constantly is going to have you violate the terms of service on these accounts very quickly.